# Get TFS ServerVersion using TfsTeamProjectCollection

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm using `TfsTeamProjectCollection` to get the list of collection in the TFS Uri but I need to know the requested Uri is TFS2013  or TFS2015; I have used the below code to find the `BuildServerVersion`

```
var tfsServerVersion = collection.GetService<IBuildServer>().BuildServerVersion;
```

I can see V1, V2, V3, V4, V5 but how do I know which version they are(I mean TFS2013 or TFS2015).

and there is no supportive reference for `enum BuildServerVersion` @ MSDN too

Suggest me how to find the TFS server version for the requested Uri.

Comment: Are you using  old XAML build?

Answer (score 0):

Just as what you have done using the `IBuildServer` interface from `Build.Client` to get the version of the server.

```
//V3 for 2010,V4 for 2012,V5 for 2013 and 2015
```

For TFS 2013 and TFS 2015, they are using the same build process template.

---

**Update**

*Add a uservoice:*

> **Be able to get installed TFS version by using TFS API or Rest API**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19025407-be-able-to-get-installed-tfs-version-by-using-tfs

Comment: I appreciate. Thanks. but How do I differentiate the URI is from TFS 2013 or TFS 2015? and later if any of the tfs url from 2017????

Comment: @sankar2.0 For now it's not able to do this by TFS API or Rest API. I have crated a uservoice for you, you could vote up for it to get more attention. TFS PM will review the idea. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19025407-be-able-to-get-installed-tfs-version-by-using-tfs